# How can Room database update my RecyclerView in the UI when I have added a new item to the database using Coroutines?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I am using Android Architecture components to create a todo android application which will have a list of Notes. Each note will have a list of todo items similar to how Google Keep Notes works. So, you can edit a note, update contents of the todo items, add more todo items, and when you completed a todo item, you click the checkbox and it disappears from the todo list and appears in the done list. I am using Room database, and using dependency injection with Hilt to inject my repository to the viewModel. My issue is that when I try to create a new todo item in a note, it gets created in room since the DAO does that operation in a coroutine, but my recyclerView never gets updated even if my recyclerview gets livedata from the roomdatabase. Is there something I may be missing? **(My problem is in the ToDoListViewModel and ToDoListFragment)**

Here is a link to my repository.
https://bitbucket.org/fco2/chuka-notes/src/main_feature/

I have tried to debug and figure out what I am doing wrong or if what I am doing is probably impossible, but I believe it is possible, but I may just be missing something in my steps.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to look at it and offer feedback!

Here are some code snippets:
ToDoListFragment.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ToDoListFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentToDoListBinding
    private val viewModel: ToDoListViewModel by viewModels()
    private val args: ToDoListFragmentArgs by navArgs()
    private lateinit var toDoListAdapter: ToDoListAdapter
    //private lateinit var completedListAdapter: ToDoCompletedListAdapter
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentToDoListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        binding.addToDoItemBtn.supportImageTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(requireContext(), R.color.colorWhite)
        binding.toDoTextTitle.setText(args.noteTitle)
        initializeToDoListRecyclerView()
        binding.addToDoItemBtn.setOnClickListener { addToDoNote() }
        performBackPressedAction()
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun initializeToDoListRecyclerView(){
        val manager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        toDoListAdapter = ToDoListAdapter(ToDoListClickListener { toDoItem, view ->
            performViewClickAction(toDoItem, view)
        })
        binding.toDoListRecyclerView.apply{
            layoutManager = manager
            adapter = toDoListAdapter
        }

        if(args.noteId == -1L)
            viewModel.addToToDoList()
        viewModel.toDoList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { updatedList ->
            toDoListAdapter.differ.submitList(updatedList)
            setProgressBarAndDividerVisibility(updatedList)
            Timber.d("CHUKA - todo _> actual list observer size ${updatedList.size}")
        })
        //viewModel.resetDb()
    }

    private fun setProgressBarAndDividerVisibility(updatedList: List<ToDoItem>) {
        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        if (updatedList.isNotEmpty())
            binding.divider.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        else
            binding.divider.visibility = View.GONE
    }

     private fun addToDoNote(){
        if(args.noteId == -1L){
            viewModel.addToToDoList()
        }else{
            saveNoteAndToDoItem()
        }
    }
    
    private fun saveNoteAndToDoItem(){
        val note = Note().apply{
            title = binding.toDoTextTitle.text.toString()
            label = "Android"
            id = args.noteId
        }

        val toDoItem = ToDoItem().apply {
            isCompleted = viewModel.currentIsCompleted.value!!
            message = viewModel.currentTextEdit.value!!
        }
        if( viewModel.currentToDoItemId.value != null && viewModel.currentToDoItemId.value != -1L)
            toDoItem.id = viewModel.currentToDoItemId.value!!
        //not setting noteId here because if you are creating a new note, you need to get the notId after it is created
        viewModel.saveNoteAndToDoItem(note, toDoItem)
    }
}
```

Note.kt and ToDoItem.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = "note")
data class Note(
    var title: String = "<No Title>",
    var label: String = "",
    var color: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_updated")
    var lastUpdated: Date? = null
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long? = null
}

@Entity(tableName = "to_do_item")
data class ToDoItem(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_id")
    var noteId: Long = 0L,
    var message: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_completed")
    var isCompleted: Boolean = false,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date_completed")
    var dateCompleted: Date? = null
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long? = null
}
```

ToDoListViewModel.kt

```
class ToDoListViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
        @Assisted val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
        private val repository: NoteAndToDoRepository
) : ViewModel(){

    var noteId : Long? = savedStateHandle.get<Long?>("noteId")!!
    fun toDoList() = repository.getAllToDoItemsFor(noteId!!).asLiveData()
    //val completedList : LiveData<MutableList<ToDoItem>> = repository.getAllCompletedItemsFor(noteId.value!!)

    private val _currentTextEdit = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val currentTextEdit: LiveData<String> = _currentTextEdit

    private val _currentIsCompleted = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val currentIsCompleted : LiveData<Boolean> = _currentIsCompleted

    private val _currentToDoItemId = MutableLiveData<Long>()
    val currentToDoItemId : LiveData<Long> = _currentToDoItemId

    fun setCurrentTextEdit(s: String){
        _currentTextEdit.value = s
    }

    fun setCurrentIsCompleted(t: Boolean){
        _currentIsCompleted.value = t
    }

    fun setCurrentToDoItemId(l: Long){
        _currentToDoItemId.value = l
    }

    private val _savedNote = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val savedNote : LiveData<Boolean> = _savedNote

    init{
        _currentTextEdit.value = ""
        _currentIsCompleted.value = false
    }

    fun setSavedNote(state: Boolean){
        _savedNote.postValue(state)
    }

    fun addToToDoList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            //if
            if (noteId == -1L || noteId == null) {
                noteId = repository.upsertNote(Note())
                Timber.d("CHUKA - todo _>  Note is NULL")
            }
            val itemToAdd = ToDoItem(noteId!!)
            Timber.d("CHUKA - todo _>  itemToAdd: $itemToAdd")
            _currentToDoItemId.value = repository.upsertToDoItem(itemToAdd) // this is what is supposed to trigger recyclerview update.
        }
    }

    fun saveNoteAndToDoItem(note: Note, toDoItem: ToDoItem) = viewModelScope.launch {
        //Timber.d("CHUKA - todo _>  called saveNoteAndToDoItem , noteId: ${note.id} todoId: ${toDoItem.id}")

        //save note
        noteId = repository.upsertNote(note)
        //save toDoItem  || note that to-do id is still probably null here
        //update noteId for toDoItem
        toDoItem.noteId = noteId!!
        repository.upsertToDoItem(toDoItem)
        Timber.d("CHUKA - todo _>  noteId: $noteId, -- ${note}, -- $toDoItem")
        setCurrentTextEdit("")
        setCurrentToDoItemId(currentToDoItemId.value!!)
    }
}
```

NoteAndToDoItemDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface NoteAndToDoItemDao {

    //get all notes -
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM note")
    fun getAllNotes(): LiveData<List<NoteWithToDoItem>>

    //insert note
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun upsertNote(note: Note): Long

    //get all to-do items 
    @Query("SELECT * FROM to_do_item WHERE note_id = :noteId AND is_completed = 0")
    fun getAllToDoItemsFor(noteId: Long): Flow<List<ToDoItem>>

    //upsert to-do item
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun upsertToDoItem(toDoItem: ToDoItem): Long
}
```

My AppModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object ChukaNotesAppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun getDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context, ToDoItemsDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME
    ).build()

    //.addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun getNoteAndToDoItemDao(database: ToDoItemsDatabase) = database.getToDoItemsDao()

    //Room Migrations
    private val MIGRATION_1_2: Migration = object : Migration(1, 2) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            // Since we didn't alter the table, there's nothing else to do here.
        }
    }
}
```

ToDoListAdapter.kt

```
class ToDoListAdapter(private val clickListener: ToDoListClickListener)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<ToDoListAdapter.ToDoListViewHolder>() {

    class ToDoListViewHolder(private var binding: ComponentToDoItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        fun bind(toDoItem: ToDoItem, clickListener: ToDoListClickListener) {
            binding.toDoItem = toDoItem
            binding.clickListener = clickListener
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object{
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ToDoListViewHolder {
                val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = ComponentToDoItemBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
                return ToDoListViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }

    private val differCallback = object: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ToDoItem>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ToDoItem, newItem: ToDoItem): Boolean {
            Timber.d("CHUKA - todo _>  areItemsTheSame")
            return oldItem.message == newItem.message  && oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ToDoItem, newItem: ToDoItem): Boolean {
            Timber.d("CHUKA - todo _>  areContentsTheSame")
            return oldItem.hashCode() == newItem.hashCode()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ToDoListViewHolder {
        return ToDoListViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ToDoListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val toDoItem = differ.currentList[position]!!
        holder.bind(toDoItem, clickListener)
    }

    val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = differ.currentList.size
}


class ToDoListClickListener(val clickListener: (ToDoItem, View) -> Unit){
    fun onClick(toDoItem: ToDoItem, view: View) = clickListener(toDoItem, view)
}
```

Comment: have you checked the observer is working

Comment: I'm not really sure but I think in the adapter you should pass something for your View that you give to onClick as parameter . holder.bind (toDoitem , clicklisttener.onClick(toDoItem , Text View or somthing).

Comment: Bahador, thanks for your suggestion.I am actually passing that from the view using dataBinding. If you look at the component_to_do_item.xml from the link above, I am passing it into the onClick function.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the above issue using Kotlin Flow, and then listened for the result in the viewModel using the Flow collect function.

Comment: Yes, this is the right solution